# Sum in list with the same name

Tags: python, list, sum

Given a list of turple format as `[(Currency1, amount1),(Currency2, amount2)]`, I would like to sum every amount by key currency, but it does not work. I tried:

```
    >>> mylist=[(‘USD’,1000),(‘THB’,25),(‘USD’,3500)]
    >>> for i in mylist:
...         sum += i[1]
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File “<stdin>“, line 2, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: ‘builtin_function_or_method’ and ‘int’
>>>
```

I wonder how can I total the amount by currency which will return as list of turple like this:
`[(‘USD’, 4500), (‘THB’, 25)]`
Please kindly help thanks.

Comment: what's your expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case you want to sum up the values of the same currency, this can help:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(int)

for k,v in mylist:
    my_dict[k] += v

print(my_dict)   
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'USD': 4500, 'THB': 25})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mylist=[('USD',1000),('THB',25),('USD',3500)]

# Initialise the aggregator dictionary
res = {}

# Populate the aggregator dictionary
for cur, val in mylist:
    if cur in res:
        # If the currency already exists, add the value to its total
        res[cur] += val
    else:
        # else create a new key/value pair in the dictionary.
        res[cur] = val

# And some nice output
for key in res:
    print('{:>5}: {:>6}'.format(key, res[key]))
```